# Rotate an object like OrbitControls but only the object itself

Tags: three.js

We love three.js! And here is a page we built using it a few years ago.
https://www.jgprolock.com

We are in the process of revising the animations on this site.

Once the page loads, the user has the ability to drag and rotate the object. But it is really a trick. We are using orbit controls to rotate the camera around our scene, and thus our main object which is centered in the scene (positions x,y,z all equal to 0). If we did not place the object in the center, it starts to look uneven in its rotation as the camera now is rotating around a center that the object doesn't have.

In order to make it look like the object is on the left side, we ended up moving the canvas to the left and then we bring it back to the right or left as the animation continues after scrolling.

So, my question is .. does anyone have an example how to achieve this functionality just by rotating the actual object itself, instead of rotating the camera around the entire scene using the orbit controls plugin?

Or is there  away to modify the orbit controls to rotate around an object and not the entire scene?

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for this for a while but right after asking this question I came across this link, which actually has an example of what we are trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/n6u6asza/1205/

The key to making this work as copied from the link: (although I am not 100% sure what this all means)

```
/* */
var isDragging = false;
var previousMousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
$(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
})
.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
    };

    if(isDragging) {

        var deltaRotationQuaternion = new three.Quaternion()
            .setFromEuler(new three.Euler(
                toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                0,
                'XYZ'
            ));

        cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
    }

    previousMousePosition = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
    };
});
/* */
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want an article on how to achieve this without the use of unnecessary jquery dependencies you can have a look [here](https://daniel-ellis.medium.com/dc79ee545d85)

This uses the eventListener to find a `mousemove` event whilst a `mousedown` event is occurring, and then passes the coordinates to a custom function.

```js
   var mouseDown = false,
        mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0;

    var canvas = renderer.domElement    
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
            if (!mouseDown) {return}
            //console.log('drag')
            evt.preventDefault();
            var deltaX = evt.clientX - mouseX,
                deltaY = evt.clientY - mouseY;
            mouseX = evt.clientX;
            mouseY = evt.clientY;

            // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH X and Y 
            object.rotation.x += deltaX
            
        }, false);
        
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        mouseDown = true;
        mouseX = evt.clientX;
        mouseY = evt.clientY;
    }, false);
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        mouseDown = false;
    }, false);
}
```

But not that this will not work if you have OrbitControls or DragControls imported!